# angularjs Post Object To PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

how to create a variable of post json angularjs of code like the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required class="form-control" id="" ng-model="dataInsert.name" placeholder="">
      <p ng-show="form.nama.$invalid && !form.nama.$pristine" class="help-block text-danger">Don't Empty.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="room in rooms">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="room" class="flat" ng-model="dataInsert.selectRoom[room.id]">  {{room.room}}
      </label>
    </div>
```

with php file like this

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); $name = $conn->real_escape_string($data->name); $room = $conn->real_escape_string($data->room???);
```

for the variable name works well, but I was confused to make variable from $ data-> room

Please help,

Comment: try with $http in angular js it will work like ajax and in php you will get data in post variable like $_POST["name"];